# How do I query a repo and find out its content?

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, command, repository

How would I find out more information about a repo within RHEL?

For instance, I would like to know what packages it holds, as well as information on size, its description/purpose, etc. I know that you can query packages in a similar way using yum commands to find out more information about them; is there an equivalent for repos?

The information would be useful because how would you know if a repo should be enabled without knowing of its contents?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can list what repos you have available via:

`sudo dnf repolist`

or

`sudo subscription-manager repos --list`

If you want to see the contents of a particular repo you can temporarily disable all other repos and only enable the one you're interested in, like this:

`sudo dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms" repoquery --all --info`

In a more concise output you could do this:

`sudo dnf repoquery --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms" --queryformat "Name:%{name}-%{evr} Size:%{installsize} Summary:%{summary}"`

More information is available via `man dnf`, `dnf repoquery --help`, and `dnf repoquery --querytags`